# How to Get Parent node and Bold(apply any style) them in XSLT?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath

I am XSLT beginner, I need to bold or apply any style to the ancestor element. Please find the xml, xsl and required output below.

XML:

```
<group>
<elementgroup1>
<element1>value1</element1>
<element2/>
<element3>value3</element3>
</elementgroup1>
<elementgroup2>
<elementsubgroup2>
<element4>value4</element4>
<element5>value5</element5>
</elementsubgroup2>
</elementgroup2>
</group>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="table">
        <xsl:attribute name="border">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="tr">
            <xsl:element name="th">
                <xsl:text>Elements</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="th">
                <xsl:text>Values</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:element name="tr">

               <xsl:element name="td">

                   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="td">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
                    <xsl:if test="boolean(@styVal)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@styVal"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My required Output:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">group</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">elementgroup1</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">elementgroup2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">elementsubgroup2</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>element5</td>
      <td>value5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Currently coming expect this  **style="font-weight:bold"**, Kindly suggest your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will return the result you have posted as required. But perhaps you are looking for something else, since your XSLT attempt is clearly going in another direction.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>         

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, Working perfectly and I am interested to know how this *[*] catches? Its the method to catch the Ancestor? Kindly suggest

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry \*\[\*] is escaped while typing. hanks Michael, Working perfectly and I am interested to know how this  \*\[\*] catches? Its this method to catch the Ancestor? Kindly suggest.

Comment: `<xsl:template match="*[*]">` processes all elements that have a child element. These elements are the "headers" in your example, and will be styled as bold. The other template processes all other elements, i.e. elements that do not have a child element. These are the elements that carry actual values.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k, Perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You may put your required style in `<td>` directly `style='font-weight:bold'` or you can use `xsl:use-attribute-sets="set_table"` and `xsl:attribute-set`.

Comment: that I know, how will I catch the parent or ancestor from xslt?